# What should my job title be without coming across as an AH

Tags: title

I've been working in my dad's company for over a year now and it seems like it's going to stay that way for a while. Therefor I think it's about time for me to think of a title that suits my job without coming across as arrogant or super experienced.

It's a relatively small scaffolding company with a turnover of about 1.5-2 million p/y. I pretty much do everything apart from the scaffolding itself, quotes and planning.

So some of the things I do are:

- Accounts payable/receivable
- Invoicing
- Bookkeeping / Accounting
- Administration
- Customer service
- HR / recruitment
- Acquisition
- Financial analysis

Pretty much everything that has to be done in the office.

Would something like **Finance & Administration Manager** be a good one?

Comment: Do you get to pick your own title for internal use, or is this more for how you want it to be on your resumé?

Comment: At the moment mainly for my email signature, but also for my linkedin/facebook profile (which I think has the same porpose as a resume).

Comment: Depending on how long you've been working there, a large loaded title might come off as odd. However titles have become increasingly less important, and I've seen some ridiculous ones. Usually your job experience on your CV is vastly more important than whatever label you put on it. And quite often the assumption is that you had no control of your title and as such it says very little about you.

Comment: Also see this thread: http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/3880/how-should-a-job-with-no-official-title-be-listed-on-a-resume/3899#3899
Maybe you could just keep it as simple as possible, e.g. "Manager". If it's for a CV you can list your specific skills. If it's for external, then it's broad enough that people don't ask "which manager do I need?"

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I choose an appropriate job title?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/22172/how-do-i-choose-an-appropriate-job-title)

Comment: If you are not supervising people, you are not a manager

Answer (score 4):

A job title **on a resume** helps you get a job by showing you have already held the same job, or a job that's considered a prerequisite, as the job you're trying to get. You're not trying to get a job, so this is irrelevant.

A job title on fb/linkedin can serve the same purpose as a resume, or can be simply for showing off to friends and family that you are now an Intermediate Assistant Analyst rather than the Junior Assistant Analyst you once were.

A job title on a business card lets people you're dealing with outside your company know what your job is and what they should and shouldn't discuss with you. Same holds for an email signature.

The first case doesn't apply (you believe you may work in the family firm indefinitely) and the second is offtopic here (tell your high school friends you're the VP if you like, whatever.) So that leaves the third item.

I laughed aloud when you said you did "everything" except, you know, what the firm actually does for money - scaffolding, selling scaffolding jobs, and planning how to get the jobs done with the people and equipment you have. Those three things are "everything" - what you're doing is important, but it's nowhere near everything. If I read "Finance and Administration Manager" I would expect the person decided whether the company needed loans, or to buy new equipment, as well as setting revenue goals and such. I think that's a little over your head. "Office Manager" wouldn't be bad. Or "Finance and Administration Clerk", though Clerk is pretty old fashioned these days. You could try for something modern, funny, and hip, like "Head Paper Herder" or "Chaos Master" if you think your customers would get it.

Or you could not worry about it. Especially if your last name is the same as your dad's, people who exchange emails are likely to know your role. You're pitching in and doing what needs to be done, and your father trusts you with millions of dollars. That's more valuable than any title you can make up.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on your future plans. You have been doing a little of everything at current company, but in the future you will inevitably want/need to specialize. It will be to your advantage to develop a narrower, more focused job profile. 
That way should you ever decide to abandon the nest and work for another company, they will know what to do with you. So you need a job title that:

a. will help your future employer decide where you fit in,

b. accurately reflects your main professional strength (e.g. is it accounting, customer service, or HR -- it cannot be all three), and

c. reflects your own interests and plans - where you WANT to go professionally.

I think you are getting excellent experience wearing many hats in your current role, but in a year or two it might be time to decide which hat fits best. If you are not yet "there" mentally, then you might want to table this question until a time comes when you have a better idea of what you want to be and where you want to go professionally. Good luck!